# Completion of a Number Field at a Infinite prime

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $v$ denote an archimedean prime of a number field $K$, then we can define an absolute value on the number field wrt $v$.

1. How to see whether $K_v$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?
2. Is it possible that $K_v=\mathbb{R}$ for a complex prime $v$ and $K_v=\mathbb{C}$ for a real prime $v$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your second question, because by definition $v$ is real (resp. complex) if $K_v$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (resp. $\mathbb C$).

Comment: sorry for the confusion... I want to know, is it possible that $K_v= \mathbb{C}$ for the absolute value that we are  getting through a real embedding of $K$ inside $\mathbb{C}.$ @TokenToucan

Comment: No because if $K$ is contained in $\mathbb R$ so is it’s completion hence they’re equal (you complete with the usual norm on $\mathbb R$ for which the reals are already complete, so you can’t jump to the complex numbers)

Comment: so, you are saying completion of a number field does not depend on the embedding of the field?  if K is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ then its completion is always $\mathbb{R}$ irrespective of embeddings.@TokenToucan

Comment: No, I mean after the embedding. Certainly it is possible for a field to have some embeddings contained in the reals and some which are not.